# Sybase SQL Return First time transactions

Tags: sql, transactions, sybase

I am trying to return first time transactions on new cards. To no avail. I am trying to write a query that will return card numbers that have performed transactions for the first time on a specified date. This is my query, but it gives me card numbers that have performed transactions previously on earlier dates.

```
SELECT TOP 1 trans_date, card_num 
FROM e_transaction 
where trans_date between '20161004 00:00' and '20161004  23:59'
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result. `Top` without `Order By` does not make any sense

Comment: TOP 1, but no ORDER BY?

Comment: Update your question and show us sample data along with desired output.

Comment: Sample data and expected output has been provided

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the earliest transaction date coincides with the first transaction date for a card, you can try the following `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT MIN(trans_date), card_num
FROM e_transaction
GROUP BY card_num
HAVING MIN(trans_date) BETWEEN '20161004 00:00' AND '20161004 23:59'
```

Trans_Date....Card_Num....Trans_Amount;

10/2/2016.....21345...............500;

10/2/2016.....21345................600;

10/4/2016.....21114...............300;

10/4/2016.....21734...............600;

9/4/2016......21734................400

Assuming this was the table, my query should return card_num='21114' and Trans_Amount='300' being that there is no previous transaction history on this card number. Other card numbers would not be returned as they have previous transaction history or occurrence on earlier dates.